# How can I make an object render with a wireframe in the game engine?

Tags: game-engine, wireframe

I want it to look like the top image when I press <kbd>P</kbd>, so it has those lines around each face.

Like this:

[image]

Not like this:

[image]

Comment: I didn't explain well, I want it to be like the top image, not the bottom, when I press "p"

Comment: Does starting the game engine in wireframe mode work for you? (press `Z` to enter wireframe mode, then press `P`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to create a wireframe material. A quick 'n' dirty way to do generate a wireframe texture is described below:

1. Unwrap your model. If you don't know how to do this simply select everything and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> > *Mark Seam*.
2. Press <kbd>U</kbd> > *Unwrap*.
3. Open up a UV/Image editor:

   [image]
4. Click *UVs* > *Export UV Layout*. Remember where you save this image.
5. Press <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>O</kbd> to open a texture, then select the saved image.
6. Tada!

   [image]

You may want to remove the transparency in an image editor if you want your model to be opaque.