# Multiple materials in BGE

Tags: rendering, game-engine, materials, objects

I have an object with a single mesh, and it has a subdivision surface modifier on it. I'm using BGE, and I cannot figure out, how to render both the wireframe (let's say in white) and the faces (let's say in red) of this object at the same time.

Comment: is it okay if you duplicate the mesh and assign one of them to a material with wire render ?

Comment: @Chebhou unfortunately not, because the vertices of the mesh will be modified on-the-fly, and I don't want to modify the two at the same time with the same amount, that is just an unnecessary overhead...

Comment: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6361/how-can-i-make-an-object-render-with-a-wireframe-in-the-game-engine maybe this isn't exactly what you need, but it sounds good! You can just use an overlay texture on it with alpha transparency that you gather from unwrapp!